# Trilogy of books with vibroswords and hoverboards with energy shields

Tags: story-identification, books

So here goes, here's everything I remember about the novel series.

I believe it was a late 80's/early 90's trilogy. I remember it had like, vibroswords, and hoverboards with energy shields, and that the hero was named starkiller, or skykiller, or something like that, that's so close to Star Wars, that it's super unhelpful. And that he was trying to overthrow some evil empire or something because he was the rightful king. Pretty sure he was young too, not really sure about the age range.

I vividly remember one scene where the characters were leading a rebellion in a big city, flying around in hoverboard/cars, with shots pinging off their shields.

I'm pretty sure it was SF, and it's not the Star of the Guardians series. I'm also pretty sure there weren't any aliens: it was all humans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.  Was this straight-up SF or magitechnical fantasy?

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm pretty sure it was SF, and it's not the Star of the Guardians series, although that tricked me into thinking it was. I vividly remember one scene where the characters were leading a rebellion in a big city, flying around in hoverboard/cars, with shots pinging off their shields. Pretty sure he was young too, not really sure about the age range.

Comment: Oh, and I'm pretty sure there weren't any aliens, it was all humans

Comment: Could it have been something Star Wars?  From what I've read, vibroswords and Starkiller are all part of the SW universe. (Inter alia)

Comment: I just took a look at what TV Tropes has to say about that type of weapon. At https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Vibroweapon, if you click on the folder called "Literature," you can see a list of examples from published novels, but none of them appear to be the trilogy being asked about here. (I've read nearly all of the works mentioned as Literature examples.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly Simon R Green's [Deathstalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker_(series)) series.

The first book dates from 1995, though there are a couple of related books from slightly earlier; those books fill in background on a couple of minor characters.

The main character, called Owen Deathstalker, is an historian, who wants nothing more than to be left to his studies. But he is made an outlaw by the Empress, and forced to fight for his survival by engaging in a rebellion against the current regime.

It's an enjoyable, space-opera read, and includes all the elements you mention - people carry personal shields to defend against energy weapons, while vibro-swords (and indeed regular swords) are fairly common. Hover vehicles are common - there's one scene where corporate raiders take the name very literally, and attack a rival corporation's headquarters, smashing in the windows using their hovercars, and Deathstalker does more escaping via hovercar than I can recall - I mentioned the space opera part, I believe...

Aside from the above-mentioned prequel, the main trilogy is three books (Deathstalker; Deathstalker Rebellion; And Deathstalker War), and seven or so additional books - a couple with the same characters, and a whole new series set a few hundred years later with descendants of the original characters

Comment: Pretty sure this is it, thank you so much! I've been looking for this for years now.